# List insert replace all sublist with the latest insert sublist

Tags: python

```
 y=[]
 x[0]=1
 x[1]=2
 y.insert(len(y),x)
 x[0]=3
 x[1]=4
 y.insert(len(y),x)
 y
 [[3,4],[3,4]]
```

The above code is tested on python shell interpreter, my question, why does the line y.insert(len(y),x) replace all sublist of y witht he latest sublist x content ? it obviously not the correct way to insert sublist with changing content, what is the correct way then ?

Comment: This is not clear, could you elaborate?

Comment: `y.insert(len(y),x)` adds a 'reference' of `x` to `y`. You might want `y.insert(len(y),x[:])`, that adds a copy of `x` to `y`

Comment: I have created a empty list y=[ ], then I add a sublist x to y with insert command. After that my program will read through the file line and replace sublist x with new content. using insert command to insert sublist x to y. why at the 2nd insert command, the sublist in index 0 get replace in y with the same content in sublist index1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `y[0]` and `y[1]` are referring to the same elements of `x`. Even though you change the content of `x` after `y`'s first insert, still it ill be referring to the `x`. You can clearly understand, if you print the value of `y` right after the first insert. You can also print the ids of first and second element of `y`, the ids will be same. Use below:

```py
print(id(y[0]), id(y[1]))
```

To achieve what you require, you need to insert like below:

```py
y.insert(len(y),list(x))
```

Using `list(x)` will create a new and fresh data.